# Livewire simple dropdown and save button with model property binding

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

In my view I have:

```
<form wire:submit.prevent="save">

    <select wire:model.defer="post.is_public">
        <option value="0">No</option>
        <option value="1">Yes</option>
    </select>

    <button type="submit">
        Submit
    </button>
    
</form>
```

And in the component:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Post;

class PostPublicToggle extends Component
{
    public Post $post;

    protected $rules = [
        'post.is_public' => 'boolean'
    ];

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.post-public-toggle');
    }

    public function save()
    {
        $this->validate();
        $this->post->save();
    }
}
```

First I wanted this to work without a submit button (auto-submit on select change). But that didn't work so that's why I added `.defer` and a submit button.

Now when I press submit, I can see in the XHR request that `post.is_public = null` and I don't understand why.

Comment: In Livewire v2 you can :-) https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties#binding-models

Comment: Oh then mey be `.defer` causing error

Comment: If I remove `.defer` it will directly submit a request when I change the dropdown value, which is not what should happen if I want to use the submit button. And also: I then still have the same problem that the value submitted is always `null`.

Comment: Have you set a default value for `post.is_public`?

Comment: I haven't explicitly no. I was assuming that if you bind to a model property it will take the value of that property?